# how {...props} works in React js

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I am bit confused how {...props} works in React-js

Usual format of object de-structuring is

```
var {a ,b ,c] = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

But I am able to use <Component {...props} /> and able to access same props from child component without assignment

Comment: That's a feature of JSX, it works in the very same way of object de-structuring, assinging each property of `prop` to the corresponding on `Component`.

Comment: This is called spreading (as opposed to destructuring) and you can read about how it works in JSX [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) although it might help to understand [how object spreading works in vanilla js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as well.